# Drupal views: how to delete a row from table in view

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

i have to delete a row from table in a view...

i have to just remove particular row from a view not deleting the node.. and i have to print only these selected rows...

is that possible in any other way..

i have tried with drupal views checkboxex but it is still in development phase i m unable to do that

any other solution for this.....

Answer (score 4):

You should add a filter to the view and filter by node ID, setting it to either only include nodes of a certain ID or alternatively exclude nodes of a certain ID.

More information about filters is here: http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/help/views/filter